# Creating Stripe transactions without recreating the user each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have been working on a Rails shopping cart app and noticed that the example code in Stripe's API creates a new customer every time I put a (test) order through.

This is obviously undesirable, and as a Ruby/Rails newbie, I've been scouring SO and every tutorial I can find to figure out how to have it check to see if the customer exists before creating it. The standard way of doing it seems to be to check for stripe_customer_token and proceed based on whether or not one is present. But no matter how I approach it, I get a NoMethodError for customer_token.

This is my current charges_controller.rb:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    if self.customer_token.present?
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_token)
    else
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => self.manager.email, card => stripe_token
    )
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (params[:amount].to_f * 100).abs.to_i,
        currency => "usd",
        card => params[:stripeToken],
        description => params[:email]
      )
      @amount = params[:amount]
      @payment_id = charge.id
    end
  end
end
```

What I get from the server is:

```
Started POST "/charges" for 50.184.82.198 at 2015-06-08 21:26:57 +0000
Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BLAHBLAHBLAH", "stripeToken"=>"BLAHBLAH", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"danicastone@gmail.com"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `customer_token' for #<ChargesController:0x007fa788783638>):
app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:48:in `create'
```

Lines 48 and 49 are:

```
if self.customer_token.present?
@customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_token)
```

(the line numbers are so high because there's a fair bit of commented-out code above that with different things I've tried)

What's strange (to my neophyte mind) is that it craps out at stripe_customer_token, but if I change stripe_customer_token to customer_token, it craps out at the line before it -- at self.customer_token. Surely if that were a problem it should be crapping out there regardless of what's on line 49?

More importantly, can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here, or on any solutions that I may have missed on this site? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are requesting the `customer_token`from the controller, rather than from the current_user. Is `stripe_customer_token` something that is stored on the user? And are you wanting to check if that is there before you fetch the customer? If so…

Change:

```
if self.customer_token.present?
```

to:

```
if current_user.stripe_customer_token.present?
```